# Setting a Label's Content Property in Code Behind

Tags: wpf, winforms, label

In a WPF I have a label:

```
<Label Name="lblTest" Content="This is a label"></Label>
```

If a was using a winform I could do this in the code behind

```
lblTest.Content="Changed Content";
```

and lblTest's new Content would be "Changed Content". What is WPF's equivalent to that. I did browse the net and search stackoverflow, but I either couldn't find it or didn't understand what people were saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly the same in WPF. (It may not work if the control is not static, e.g. if it's part of a resource or template)

Comment: Is there a using that I need to include or something, because Microsoft's Intellisense doesn't seem to pick up any of my controls.

Comment: @Stylzs05: In the code behind file of the XAML where you declared them? You do not need anything, the XAML just needs to be properly linked via namespace and class name/[`x:Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752309.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Your link bought me to the MSDN in German lol. My classname was incorrect.

Comment: @Stylzs05: Oh woops, someone else must have linked there before and it's been in my browser history since then :P